# How to remove the bottom input field?

Tags: html, forms, input, html-datalist

I am working on a form in which user needs to select the country. User can select his/her country by searching on the input field or by selecting from the dropdown.

All of the countries are shown in dropdown so I've removed them for the purpose to post minimized code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="country">Country </label>
    <input list="country" name="country">
    <datalist class="form-control" id="country">
        <option value="Virgin Islands (Brit)">
        <option value="Virgin Islands (USA)">
        <option value="Wake Island">
        <option value="Wallis & Futana Is">
        <option value="Yemen">
        <option value="Zaire">
        <option value="Zambia">
        <option value="Zimbabwe">
    </datalist>
</div>
```

An screenshot of the current state is here:

[image]

The form shouldn't have that extra input field below the Country label. The field isn't accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

[image: This is using your code]

```
This is using your code
```

Maybe there is another code that you don't know.
You can inspect element your code by press f12 button

I hope my answer can help you

Comment: so,I was using bootstrap and due to using form-group class it happened. Thank You

Comment: Oke, no problem